# making jQuery Masonry responsive for iPhone/iPad

Tags: css, media-queries, jquery-masonry

I'm adapting the Masonry Tumblelog layout so that the single column width is 320px and multiples of that for two/three columns etc, so that it will work for iPhone and up.

I'm using media queries to squash the all columns down to the 320 for iPhone. It's kind of working, i.e. it's stacking and reducing to one column. Problem is that it is tiny on the iPhone screen, covering only about a 5th of the width. I've followed the css elements from the div upwards and all are set to 320 in the media queries. The site is at http://www.4pixels.com. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I use the code here : http://www.maurizioconventi.com/2012/06/19/responsive-example-integrating-twitter-bootstrap-and-jquery-masonry/

It adjusts the column width according to the container's width. Take a look.

Comment: Pointless comment. It is now 404. You should have added the snippet here.